# "Illegal instruction" if "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" is set correctly when importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have cuda 8.0, 9.0 and 9.1 installed on my system with `/usr/local/cuda` pointing to `/usr/local/cuda-9.0` and if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty I get the typical `ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` error when importing tensorflow (tensorflow-gpu==1.7.0 installed over pip).

If I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH` according to the [Nvidia documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#environment-setup) to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64` and `PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:...` I get an `Illegal instruction (core dumped)` when importing tensorflow. The same thing happens if i set `CUDA_HOME` to `/usr/local/cuda-9.0/`.

cuDNN is version 7.0.4.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Please provide additional information: What version of tensorflow are you using, how did you install it?

Comment: Try to set cuda 8.0 in LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH

Comment: You need cuda 9.0 for tensorflow 1.7.0 according to the [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#tested_source_configurations)